# R add to a list in a loop, using conditions

Tags: r

I have a data.frame dim = (200,500)

I want to do a `shaprio.test` on each column of my dataframe and append to a list. This is what I'm trying:

```
 colstoremove <- list();
 for (i in range(dim(I.df.nocov)[2])) {
     x <- shapiro.test(I.df.nocov[1:200,i])
     colstoremove[[i]] <- x[2]
    }
```

However this is failing. Some pointers? (background is mainly python, not much of an R user)

Comment: why are you using range to generate your loop index? use `i in seq_along(I.df.nocov)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `lapply()` as any data frame passed into it runs operations on columns and the returned list will be equal to number of columns:

```
colstoremove <- lapply(I.df.noconv, function(col) shapiro.test(col)[2])
```

Comment: in situations like this I like using `function(col) shapiro.test(col)[2]` to emphasise that `lapply` is acting on the columns of the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what happens in

```
for (i in range(dim(I.df.nocov)[2]))
```

For the sake of example, I assume that `I.df.nocov` contains 100 rows and 5 columns.

`dim(I.df.nocov)` is the vector of `I.df.nocov` dimensions, i.e. c(100, 5)

`dim(I.df.nocov)[2]` is the 2nd dimension of `I.df.nocov`, i.e. 5

`range(x)`is a 2-element vector which contains minimal and maximal values of x.  For example, range(c(4,10,1)) is c(1,10).  So `range(dim(I.df.nocov)[2])` is c(5,5).

Therefore, the loop iterate twice: first time with i=5, and second time also with i=5.  Not surprising that it fails!

The problem is that R's function `range` and Python's function with the same name do completely different things.  The equivalent of Python's `range` is called `seq`.  For example, `seq(5)=c(1,2,3,4,5)`, while `seq(3,5)=c(3,4,5)`, and `seq(1,10,2)=c(1,3,5,7,9)`. You may also write `1:n`, it is the same as `seq(n)`, and `m:n` is same as `seq(m,n)` (but the priority of ':' is very high, so `1:2*x`  is interpreted as `(1:2)*x`.

Generally, if something does not work in R, you should print the subexpressions from the innerwise to the outerwise.  If some subexpression is too big to be printed, use str(x) (str means "structure").  And never assume that functions in Python and R are same!  If there is a function with same name, it usually does a different thing.

On a side note, instead of `dim(I.df.nocov)[2]` you could just write `ncol(I.df.nocov)` (there is also a function `nrow`).